# dashboard component snapshot via code

Tags: dashboard, connect-api

Is there a way to take snapshot of a dashboard component and get the url of the image, all via code?

I tried to use ConnectApi.DashboardComponentSnapshot, but i get error saying i can't construct a snapshot outside a test. Here is the code i was trying (i have hardcoded dashboardId, componentId, dashboardName, etc)

```
ConnectApi.DashboardComponentSnapshot dashboardSnap = new ConnectApi.DashboardComponentSnapshot();
dashboardSnap.componentId = '01a30000003G6qE';
dashboardSnap.componentName = 'Sample Component Name';
dashboardSnap.dashboardId = '01Z30000001HjMK';
dashboardSnap.dashboardName = 'Sample Dashboard Name';

String myURL = String.ValueOf(dashboardSnap.thumbnailUrl);
System.debug(myURL);
```

But above code doesnt really work. Even if i put it in a class and call the method, i still get the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Having the same issue....please update if you found any solution